# How I can get a ArrayList out of a intern txt file in App_Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, arraylist, appdata

I want to get a ArrayList out of my intern txt file in App_Data Folder.

I have in my ASP.NET Application a App_Data Folder wit a file how this content:

```
P1
AS5050
GMS4010
GMS4020
GMS4030
GMS4030A
gateway
view_only
AS5050
```

and I want to get this list in a ArraList.

Comment: If this data P1 AS5050 seperated with \r\n delimeter character then File.ReadAllLines will give you ArrayList of String

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs on old days when C# doesn't have _generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = new ArrayList(File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourfile));
```

But... why an `ArrayList` ? Generic List would be better in 2013 !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(File.ReadAllLines(path));
```

but I'll strongly recommend `List<T>` over `ArrayList` unless you're using .net 1.0 or 1.1

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));
```